# Is there a way to insert text in table shape through copy/paste from e.g. excel rather than editing row by row?

Tags: draw.io

I'd like to create in draw.io a table shape with many rows with containing the text of a range of cells in MS Excel. Other than handwriting each row text, is there a way to copy paste directly all the cell values?